# How to change records in table to name a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

In SQL I have a table with 3 column, include of :

```
ID      NLV         SGLV
m0001   27/03/2017  8
m0001   28/03/2017  3.5
m0002   28/03/2017  8
m0003   26/03/2017  12
M0001   27/03/2017  2
```

Now, I want to write an SQL query to create a new table have format follow:

```
ID  SUM(SGLV)   26 (26/03/2017) 27 (27/03/2017) 28 (28/03/2017)
M0001   13.5    0               10              3.5
m0002   8       0               0               8
m0003   12      12              0               0
```

So, can anybody help me?

Comment: SQL Server Or MySQL?? Make sure you tagged correct RDBMS..

Comment: Your data only has 3 day (26, 27 ,28) or more?

Comment: @TriV it's example. Data include multi rows

Comment: @ShakeerMirza SQL server, I fixed

Comment: I want to calculate how many hours of each people in a month group by day. So, table shall include about 30 column from day 1 to day 30 in a month. I think should use CASE WHEN ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, follow @Gaurav Rajput I'm successed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, below query gives you the required output

```
DECLARE @SAMPLEDATA TABLE(ID VARCHAR(100),     NLV  DATETIME,       SGLV DECIMAL(18,1))
INSERT INTO @SAMPLEDATA VALUES
('m0001',   '03/27/2017',  8),
('m0001',   '03/28/2017',  3.5),
('m0002',   '03/28/2017',  8),
('m0003',   '03/26/2017',  12),
('M0001',   '03/27/2017',  2)

SELECT ID,ISNULL([03/26/2017],0)[03/26/2017],ISNULL([03/27/2017],0)    [03/27/2017],ISNULL([03/28/2017],0)[03/28/2017] FROM
(
    SELECT ID,NLV,SGLV FROM @SAMPLEDATA
)T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SGLV) FOR NLV IN([03/26/2017],[03/27/2017],[03/28/2017])
)PIV;
```

output

```
------------------------------------------
--ID    03/26/2017  03/27/2017  03/28/2017
------------------------------------------
m0001   0.0         10.0        3.5
m0002   0.0         0.0         8.0
m0003   12.0        0.0         0.0
------------------------------------------
```

**USING DYNAMIC QUERY** : As mentioned in comments, if output is required to be generated for current complete month then the same can be achieved using dynamic query also rather than writing CASE for each and every day of month. Try below query:

```
DECLARE @DYNAMICQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @DATERANGE VARCHAR(MAX)=''
;WITH COMPLETEMONTH (COL)
AS
(
        SELECT CAST(CAST(MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS     VARCHAR(2))+'/'+'01/'+CAST(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME)
            UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(D,1,COL)COL FROM COMPLETEMONTH 
            WHERE COL< DATEADD(D,-1,    (DATEADD(M,1,CAST(CAST(MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS     VARCHAR(2))+'/'+'01/'+CAST(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS     DATETIME))))
)
SELECT @DATERANGE=@DATERANGE+'['+CONVERT(VARCHAR,COL,101)+']'+',' FROM     COMPLETEMONTH
SET @DATERANGE=LEFT(@DATERANGE,LEN(@DATERANGE)-1)

SELECT @DYNAMICQUERY=
'SELECT ID,'+@DATERANGE+' FROM
(
    SELECT ''m0001'' ID ,   ''03/27/2017'' NLV,  8 SGLV
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ''m0001'',   ''03/28/2017'',  3.5
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ''m0002'',   ''03/28/2017'',  8
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ''m0003'',   ''03/26/2017'',  12
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ''M0001'',   ''03/27/2017'',  2
)T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SGLV) FOR NLV IN('+@DATERANGE+')
)PIV;'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @DYNAMICQUERY,N'@DATERANGE     VARCHAR(MAX)',@DATERANGE=@DATERANGE
```

Comment: Column name in output table from day 1 -> 30 every month ?

Comment: above query is based on sample data provided by you. Please add details if you have specific range of date or you want to get output for complete month by default, so that i will edit my answer and will add required details in solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE TABLE #Table1
        ([ID] varchar(5), [NLV] varchar(10), [SGLV] float)
    ;

    INSERT INTO #Table1
        ([ID], [NLV], [SGLV])
    VALUES
        ('m0001', '27/03/2017', 8),
        ('m0001', '28/03/2017', 3.5),
        ('m0002', '28/03/2017', 8),
        ('m0003', '26/03/2017', 12),
        ('M0001', '27/03/2017', 2)
    ;

    SELECT ID,ISNULL([26/03/2017],0)+ISNULL([27/03/2017],0)+ISNULL([28/03/2017],0) AS [SUM(DGLV)],
ISNULL([26/03/2017],0)'26 (26/03/2017)',ISNULL([27/03/2017],0)'27 (27/03/2017)',ISNULL([28/03/2017],0)'28 (28/03/2017)'
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM #TABLE1
) SRC
PIVOT
(
   SUM(SGLV)  
  FOR NLV IN ([26/03/2017], [27/03/2017],[28/03/2017])
) PIV;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may help you

```
select * into #temp from (

select 'm0001'ID,   '27/03/2017' as NLV ,8 SGLV
union all
select 'm0001',   '28/03/2017',  3.5
union all
select 'm0002  ', '28/03/2017' , 8
union all
select 'm0003   ','26/03/2017' ,12
union all
select 'M0001   ','27/03/2017' , 2
) as a


;with cte as (
select ID,isnull([27/03/2017],0)as [27/03/2017],isnull([28/03/2017],0)as [28/03/2017],isnull([26/03/2017],0) as [26/03/2017] from(
select * from #temp
) as a
pivot
(
 max(sglv) for nlv in ([27/03/2017],[28/03/2017],[26/03/2017])
)
as a
)
select id,[27/03/2017]+[28/03/2017]+[26/03/2017] as SUM_SGLV,[27/03/2017],[28/03/2017],[26/03/2017] from cte
```